# Yii2 kartik gridview getSelectedRows returning null keys always

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I am creating a kartik gridview for my MYSQL View.So there is no primary keys hence it is a view.
And my gridview is like

```
<?=GridView::widget([
    'id' => 'pending-ads-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    // 'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns, // check the configuration for grid columns by clicking button above
    'containerOptions' => ['style' => 'overflow: auto'], // only set when $responsive = false
    'headerRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'filterRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'pjax' => true, // pjax is set to always true for this demo
    // set your toolbar
    'toggleDataContainer' => ['class' => 'btn-group mr-2'],
    // set export properties
    'export' => [
        'fontAwesome' => true
    ],
    // parameters from the demo form
    'bordered' => false,
    'striped' => false,
    'condensed' => false,
    'responsive' => false,
    'hover' => false,
    'showPageSummary' => false,
    'panel' => [
        'type' => GridView::TYPE_DANGER,
        'heading' => "Pending Ads",
    ],
    'persistResize' => false,
    'toggleDataOptions' => ['minCount' => 9],
    // 'exportConfig' => $exportConfig,
    'itemLabelSingle' => 'product',
    'itemLabelPlural' => 'products'
]);
?>
```

And i am accessing the selected row by the below code

```
var keys = $('#pending-ads-grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```

But it is returning null key set always.How can i fix this issue

Comment: Can you show your columns? What do you use for checkbox column?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ichsanmust/yii2-grid for checkbox column

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

1-You must have a checkbox column. Add the following code to the beginning of the columns

```
'columns' => [
    [
        'class' => '\kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'
        #code....
```

2-Then open the page in the browser. **Check** the rows you want to receive (**checking boxes**)

Review HTML code through a browser. Make sure your Grid-view ID is `pending-ads-grid`. (Div tag).